# How many connected components does the following infinite graph have?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, graph-theory

Consider the undirected infinite graph whose nodes are the positive integers $1,2,3,4,...$, and where there is an edge between two nodes $n$, $m$ if and only if $\frac{n^2+n}{2} = m$. How many connected components does this graph have? How might we characterize them?

Comment: Why is that? Is there some number theoretic reason? That seems like the intuitive answer to me, given the relative sparseness of edges, but I can't give myself a concrete reason why.

Comment: Find the Laplacian of the graph and then find eigendecomposition and number of zero eigenvalues are the number of connected components

Comment: Yes, sorry. It's been awhile since I've done any graph theory, so my terminology was off. What I meant was connected components, i.e. maximal connected subgraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be infinitely many.

Note that $m$ is the sum of the numbers $1$ through $n$.

Hence, $1$ is connected to $1$, and $1$ only, so one subgraph is:

$1 \rightarrow 1$

$2$ is connected to $3$ (since $3$ is sum of $1$ and $2$), which is connected to $6$ (sum of $1$ through $3$), which is connected to $21$, etc., so you get:

$2 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 6 \rightarrow 21 \rightarrow ...$ (this one will go on forever of course)
But, you just skipped $4$, so you also get:

$4 \rightarrow 10 \rightarrow 55 \rightarrow ...$

and then you have:

$5 \rightarrow 15 \rightarrow 120 \rightarrow ....$

In fact, there will always be number that you skipped, since not every number is the sum of numbers $1$ through $n$, and hence that number will start yet another subgraph that consists of just one long linear infinite path. So, you get infinitely many of such infinitily long subgraphs, together with the $1 \rightarrow 1$ subgraph.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, your graph is the disjoint union of infinitely many half-infinite paths and one isolated vertex $1$ (or a loop if you want, because $(1^2+1)/2=1$). Each vertex $n$ has at least one, but also at most two neighbors, namely $(n^2+n)/2$ and maybe an $m$ with $(m^2+m)/2= n$. So there are infinitely many connected components, all but one being one of the paths.

Why are there infinitely many such paths? Choose some prime $p>2$. Every number that follows on $p$ in its path will be a multiple of $p$. So no prime $q>p$ will be part of this path. You see that every path can contain at most one (odd) prime, hence there must be infinitely many paths.